# UIScrollView - Prevent UIImageView as subview of UIScrollView from being dragged off screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIImageView element as a subview of my main UIScrollView element. 
I want the Image to fill out the whole screen at all times, but I can drag the edges a bit too far, so that the yellow "background" becomes visible. 
If I lift my finger, the Image "bounces" back and fills out the screen correctly.

I want to prevent this dragging of the image off screen.
I do however want the image to bounce back once I drag it out of the "safety area".

This is my ScrollView initialization:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.height, frame.size.width)];
if (self) {
    [self initImageValues];

    self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.bouncesZoom = YES;
    self.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
    self.delegate = self;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
    [self setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;

    // Load Image
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    [self addSubview:imageView];

    [self setContentSize: CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];

    // Set bigger "bounce" zone (safety area)
    self.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(-SAFETY_ZONE,-SAFETY_ZONE,-SAFETY_ZONE,-SAFETY_ZONE);

    self.scrollEnabled = YES;

}
return self;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these delegate methods:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Then read the offset and return if it's out of the "safety area".

Could be that you need another delegate method from the UIScrollView though, but a workaround like this should fix your problem :)

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. I have now included some if's that check if the image would leave the screen and then set the image position so that the image is just about on the screen. Plus the bounce is still working. Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting its `bounces` property to `NO`.

Comment: I kind of want that bounce, when I leave the "safety area" of the image. I just don't want the "bounce are" to be that big, that I can drag the image off screen.

Answer (score 0):

try setting bounces on the scrollview:

```
self.bounces = NO;
```

Comment: Okay, turning of the bounce solves the problem. But I kind of want that little bit of bounce, when I leave my "safety area" of the image. I just don't want to be able to drag the image so far, that it will leave parts of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this:
**

```
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
```

**

Comment: That does not work. I'm not sure, how the Scale of the image could influence the "bounce" when dragging the image.
Also scaling the image is not possible with this method.